# If the set of the points is closed, $f$ is not holomorphic in these points?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $f(z)=Re(z)+2Im(z)+i (2Re(z)-Im(z))^2$
> a) Determine the points $z\in\mathbb{C}$ for which $f$ is complex diffferentiable.
> b) Is $f$
> in the points found in (a) holomorphic?

My attempt:
For part a), using Cauchy-Riemann equations, I found $f$ is complex differentiable in the points $z$ s.t $4Re(z)-2Im(z)=-1$.
For part b), I still don't know how to do it. My book said since the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|4Re(z)-2Im(z)=-1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ so $f$ is not holomorphic in any these points?
My questions are:
How can the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|4Re(z)-2Im(z)=-1\}$ be closed in $\mathbb{C}$? And why from this, we can conclude $f$ is not holomorphic in any these points ?
Any help I very appreciate!

Comment: This set is the inverse image of $\{-1\}$ under a continuous map, so it is closed. For b) the argument in the book doesn't not make sense.

Comment: Hi Alex, I've added an answer. Unfortunately, it has been met with downvotes but I do recommend you check it out and the linked answer. The difference between holomorphicity and complex differentiability is important to know.

Answer (score 3):

The set $D = \{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid 4 \operatorname{Re}(z) - 2 \operatorname{Im}(z)=-1\}$ is a straight line in the complex plane. A straight line is a common example of closed sets. stoic-santiago has provided a more thorough answer to this.

I don't think $D$ being closed means anything to part b. What matters is that it has an empty interior. That is, there are no non-empty open sets contained in $D$. Hence, on no non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ is $f$ complex differentiable, and nowhere is it holomorphic.

Answer (score -1):

To see that the given set is closed in $\mathbb C$, we can use a sequential argument (there are many other ways, e.g., the set is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map.) Let $\{z_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence in $\{z\in \Bbb C: 4 \operatorname{Re}(z) - 2\operatorname{Im}(z) = -1\}$ converging to $z$. Then, $$4 \operatorname{Re}(z_n) - 2\operatorname{Im}(z_n) = -1$$ for every $n\ge 1$. Taking limits, and using the continuity of $\operatorname{Re}(\cdot)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\cdot)$, we get $$4 \operatorname{Re}(z) - 2\operatorname{Im}(z) = -1,$$
i.e., $z\in \{z\in \Bbb C: 4 \operatorname{Re}(z) - 2\operatorname{Im}(z) = -1\}$. Thus, $\{z\in \Bbb C: 4 \operatorname{Re}(z) - 2\operatorname{Im}(z) = -1\}$ is closed in $\Bbb C$.

The distinction between the terms holomorphic and differentiable is subtle. For details, I refer you to [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1630088/425395)